# Double quotes keep getting parsed in PHP's shell_exec and sed

Tags: php, bash, sed

I've spent hours trying to figure this out. I am using `shell_exec` (yes, I know the security problems associated with this) and sed to change text in a file.

The problem is no matter what I try I can't seem to output the text with the quotes still intact. I've tried almost every combination of single and double quotes I could to escape it, but it hasn't worked. After hours of trying, I decided to ask the question here.

The code is in a PHP file:

```
shell_exec('sed -i "s/patterntoreplace/yolo(word,"Hello Everyone", word)/" test.txt
```

The problem is that the file ends up with:

```
yolo(word,Hello Everyone, word)
```

The quotes keep getting parsed and I absolutely need them. I tried various things such as putting it into a variable, using `escapeshellarg` and `escapeshellcmd` and trying various combinations of single and double quotes, but I still can't get it to work.

This is very frustrating for me because this is the last part of my project and it should be simple, yet I can't run my program without the quotes. It's rather infuriating.

Can someone please tell me what to replace in that command to get quotes to output correctly?

Comment: Why doesn't [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) work for you? Why are you using `sed` anyway, and not [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) and file functions in PHP?

Comment: This works for me: `shell_exec('sed -i "s/patterntoreplace/yolo(word,\"Hello Everyone\", word)/" test.txt');`

Comment: I think your problem is simply due to the fact that you need to escape the inside quotes - see comment by @NehalJ.Wani

Comment: As mario said, it's much better to use a PHP function to do it (when you have to do this action with a PHP script of course)...

Comment: Nehal's solution worked! Hours down the drain all over missing slashes. Thanks to both Nehal and Idriss and everyone else for their help.

Comment: @steven even if it "fixes" the problem, that solution (using `sed` on a PHP script) must be avoided

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$arg = 's/patterntoreplace/yolo(word,"Hello Everyone", word)/';
$cmd = 'sed -i '.escapeshellarg($arg).' test.txt';
shell_exec($cmd);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can and should be done with PHP, no `sed` required:

```
$filename = 'test.txt';
$pattern = 'patterntoreplace';
$replace = 'yolo(word,"Hello Everyone", word)';

$lines = []; 
foreach(file($filename) as $line) {
    $lines []= preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $line);
}

file_put_contents($filename, join("", $lines));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use slashes to use the quotes again inside, but keeping the internal quotes in mind only, in your case: main quote is single

```
// have added slashes to Hello Everyone
shell_exec('sed -i "s/patterntoreplace/yolo(word,\"Hello Everyone\", word)" test.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use `\'` instead of `'` and `\"` instead of `"` where you dont wnat them to be parsed? They said that already! :)

Comment: It's not a problem with the simple quote around the command. See the @Nehal J. Wani comment ;)